# Why my ODBC query is giving me a timeout?

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have a very simple connection file:

```
<?php
$server = "SEVERIP";
$database = "SERVERINVOICE";
$user = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$connection=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

if (!$connection){
echo (die(odbc_error()));
} else {
echo "You are connected!";
}

$var1 = "88A70CCB";
$var2 = "2022-07-24";
$var3 = "WLGP881221502";
$sql  = "EXEC xpInvoiceQuerPar ?, ?, ?";

$procedure_params   = array( $var1, $var2, $var3 );
$prep               = odbc_prepare($connection,$sql);
```

It is getting the connection right. But when I add the "odbc_prepare" part, the last code line, the navigator get stuck in "waiting mode", is like is loading, waiting for an answer from the server but I never get it... After 30 min approx. I get a time out. I know is not the best way to ask this question but I don't have access to the server, only FTP and the browser. What can cause this issue? I assume the code is correct.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question, because the problem was solved but someone can still get a benefit from this. The issue was in the "procedure" it was bussy in other proccess.